# Regex for scientific number and hex and decimal numbers for vim produces error while works for Perl?

Tags: vim, centos7

I was trying to learn how to write vim plugins and required to match numbers which a language would allow to work with and trying to highlight it with different colors and wrote following regex in very magic mode:

```
 syntax match cNumberGroup "\v\d+" 
 syntax match cNumberGroup "\v0x\x+"
 syntax match cNumberGroup "\v[+\-]?(?:0|[1-9]\d*)(?:\.\d*)?(?:[eE][+\-]?\d+)?"
```

The first one is for decimal numbers. The second one for hex numbers
The third one is for scientific numbers representations.

The first two are working fine but last one is not working. I want to know that why it is not working and also that, Is there a better way to write all the regex to cover all the three number systems efficiently.

Thanks.

Comment: I get an error: `E64: ? follows nothing`.

Comment: Probably because you're using `(?:...)`, which isn't supported in Vim. Vim Regexps are not Perl-compatible. See `:help perl-patterns` for an overview of differences.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just slapping `\v` (very magic) in from of the regular expression doesn't make Vim's regular expression syntax Perl-compatible. As @Carpetsmoker has already commented, `:help perl-patterns` shows the differences.

For your example, the `(?:...)` has to be written as `\v%(...)`:

```
syntax match cNumberGroup "\v[+\-]?%(0|[1-9]\d*)%(\.\d*)?%([eE][+\-]?\d+)?"
```